# AndroidX Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, androidx

I'm making a unity plugin that uses an Android Library (.aar file) but since meta requests that apps use recent Android API LVL I need to upgrade my permissions.

I created my block that asks for permission if they are not granted, etc...
I can build my library file and compile my unity project but when clicking on the button that start this part of my plugin i get the folowing error

```
2023-11-17 10:52:04.879 24330-27755/com.ProTubevr.Test E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat;
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat;
        at com.ProTubeVR.ForceTubeVRInterface.ForceTubeVRInterface.getInstance(ForceTubeVRInterface.java:74)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~qZ3sqld2cHHy8U8GVA3JAA==/com.ProTubevr.Test-m9HJVy6eK_51zusoolGSOg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~qZ3sqld2cHHy8U8GVA3JAA==/com.ProTubevr.Test-
```

error is on line :

```java
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(pContext, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

I've spent some time looking for solutions but everything I tried did not work, here are my android files :

gradle.properties :

```gradle
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m 
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Project build.gradle dependencies :

```gradle
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

App build.gradle :

```gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 31
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:31.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
}
```

Here are the import i have in my java file:

```java
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

At first, I was not using the right Java version so I changed that.
Same thing for android core.
I had the feeling I was right this time but I still get this error (which i did not have before, i had other errors)

Any idea what I'm lacking or did wrong ? I'm not even sure if this comes from Unity or Android...